# QR decomposition in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, qr-decomposition

I saw that there are methods for doing [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), and solving linear systems using a QR method in TensorFlow, however, I cannot find a way to implement a QR decomposition in TensorFlow.

How do you perform a QR decomposition in TensorFlow?

Comment: This could be a good feature request, along the lines of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2207

Comment: Thanks, I just submitted a feature request for this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a QR decomposition is [now in tensorflow master](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#qr); it was [added last week](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/715f951eb9ca20fdcef20bb544b74dbe576734da).

> `tf.qr(input, full_matrices=None, name=None)`
>
> Computes the QR decompositions of one or more matrices.
>
> Computes the QR decomposition of each inner matrix in `tensor` such that
>   `tensor[..., :, :] = q[..., :, :] * r[..., :,:])`
>
> ```
> # a is a tensor.
> # q is a tensor of orthonormal matrices.
> # r is a tensor of upper triangular matrices.
> q, r = qr(a)
> q_full, r_full = qr(a, full_matrices=True)
> ```

Comment: I get the following error when trying to use the QR in a network. Was the gradient implemented?  LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'Qr_1' (op type: Qr)

Comment: @kstan0725 QR seems to not have a gradient defined, unfortunately.

Comment: Are there plans to add the gradient for the QR op so that it can be used in networks and cost functions?